# Logical error while setting variable

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

i have a else loop where two methods are executing,

```
static private void HandleClientStateCB(string clientName, 
                                     SPD.SPD_clientStateType state, object pb){
     //IF()
     else {
         HandlePCAEvent(myDevice, SpoServer.PCA.Event.DeviceInactive, "");
         HandlePCAEvent(myDevice, SpoServer.PCA.Event.DeviceDisconnect, "");
     }
}
```

what my requirement was whenever client disconnected that time i need to make version to null.The existing condition is like this

```
static private void HandleClientEventCB(SPD.SPD_eventType type, 
                          SPD.SPD_event this_event, object passback){
    //------------------
    string agentVersion = "0.0.0.0";
    if (this_event.variableData.Length >= 6 ){
         agentVersion = this_event.variableData[5].atr_value;
    }
}
```

So what i did is i declared a boolean variable test `private static bool test = false;`
then i used in else loop

```
static private void HandleClientStateCB(string clientName, 
                                    SPD.SPD_clientStateType state, object pb){
    //IF()
    else {
        HandlePCAEvent(myDevice, SpoServer.PCA.Event.DeviceInactive, "");
        HandlePCAEvent(myDevice, SpoServer.PCA.Event.DeviceDisconnect, "");
        test = true;
    }
}

static private void HandleClientEventCB(SPD.SPD_eventType type, 
                                     SPD.SPD_event this_event, object passback){
    //-------------------------------
    string agentVersion = "0.0.0.0";
    if (this_event.variableData.Length >= 6 && test==false ){
        agentVersion = this_event.variableData[5].atr_value;
    }
}
```

But this logic is not working,Can any body suggest any other logic so that disconnect time my version should be Null

Comment: **code-formatting** really exists and is not a unicorn.

Answer (score 1):

How do you check that device is disconnected when you set `test = true;`? If that condition is  available in `HandleClientEventCB` function just check it again. Else you need to pass `true/false` to `HandleClientEventCB` to know if device is disconnected.

As an aside don't you use different events for `DeviceActive`, `DeviceInactive`, `DeviceConnect` and `DeviceDisconnect`. If yes then you can know if `HandleClientEventCB` is being called for **disconnect** or not.

Comment: eventtype 'DeviceDisconnect' will make sure disconnect event happen,so what i did is after that
i used boolean variable to 'true' in HandleClientStateCB and passed to HandleClientEventCB

Comment: won't `SPD.SPD_eventType` tell you which event is this. Then you can check it in `HandleClientEventCB` function and set `agentVersion` to null if it is `DeviceDisconnect`.